# How to make react native component as a android library

Tags: java, android, react-native, android-library, electrode-native

### Here I want to use
react-native component into existing Android native application swith callback and other controls.like an android library

But I can't **[integrate existing Android native project into react-native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps)** and keep the root android project structure same.

Is there any possible way to full-fill this requirement?

Is **[Electrode Native](https://native.electrode.io/)** exact solution for this?

What about **[React-Native Brownfield development](https://www.callstack.com/blog/brownfield-development-with-react-native)** for this scenario ?